# why is this racket code giving me a function call error?

Tags: function, lisp, racket, function-call

i am working through this online book //htdp.org/2021-11-15/Book/index.html to learn the racket.as i progressed through the book i came across this code - this isnt my code and all it had asked of me was to change the ... with a string which i did - check below - first one is from the site - second one is the one i modified with strings as as specifed

```
(define current-color ...)


(define next-color
  (if (string=? "green" current-color) "yellow" ...))


(define current-color "red")

(define next-color
  (if (string=? "green" current-color) "yellow" "amber"))
```

and when i run it i get this error

```
(next-color "green")
function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a variable
```

am i missing something please help me out

Answer (score 0):

`next-color`, defined as:

```
(define next-color
  (if (string=? "green" current-color) "yellow" "amber"))
```

is variable, not function, so you can't call it like this: `(next-color "green")`. If you want to get its value, just type into REPL:

```
> next-color
```

Comment: To expand on this: if you intend `next-color` to be a function, you would write it as `(define (next-color) (if (string=? "green" current-color) "yellow" "amber"))` or `(define next-color (lambda () (if (string=? "green" current-color) "yellow" "amber")))`. If you want it to take an argument, you might use `(define (next-color color) (if (string=? "green" color) "yellow" "amber"))`.